# Video background in background view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background

I have a local .mp4 video that I would like to add as a background video. I've created a function:

```
func playVideo() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dronefootagecompressed", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    if let player = self.moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        player.view.sizeToFit()
        player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.Fill
        player.fullscreen = true
        player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
        player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
        player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
        player.play()
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)
    }
}
```

which is then called in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playVideo()
}
```

The video is showing up, but it seems like it's covering everything else (text labels, titles, everything), or so I assume it is. Can I make the video be in the background (if that even is the issue)?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

When I call `playVideo()` in `viewDidAppear`, the video shows up for about 2 seconds before going to a black background. The buttons are still visible. Is the video not loading properly?

Comment: Have you tried [bringSubviewToFront:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:) ?

Comment: Actually [sendSubviewToBack:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sendSubviewToBack:) might be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think putting it in viewDidAppear() method will solve the thing

Comment: I see my original text labels and titles for a brief second before going into the background.

Comment: then try putting it  self.view.insertSubview(player.view, atIndex:0)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking - is it possible to add a filter to the video? I know how to apply it to an image, but not for a video.

Comment: i think it is possible - i found stackoverflow thread with similar question for OSX here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519481/apply-core-image-filter-to-video-on-os-x-using-swift ... try to implement it in your code and see if it works